# asp.net datetime serialization returns different values on different servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, javascriptserializer

I'm retrieving a datetime from a shared database.  More precisely I'm retrieving a timespan and converting it to a datetime via `Convert.ToDateTime(timespan.ToString())`. I have two servers which operate in two different time zones.

One returns the datetime as `/Date(1402761600000)/` the other as `/Date(1402776000000)/`, that's a difference of `14400000`, or 4 hours.

Just a hunch that this is somehow timezone related (as I'm at GMT -4).

Why are my times being returned differently?  What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson, sql server, it's actually stored as a timespan which gets converted to a datetime `Convert.ToDateTime(timespan.ToString)` to be precise.

Comment: @Mate, see above.  The times are not stored with TZ information, DateTime does not introduce timezone information.  I'm thinking timezone is getting involved during serialization.  Of course it's just a hunch on my part that it's timezone related.

Comment: @Mate, what you linked is not the same as this issue.  Please re-read the second paragraph of the question to see the difference.  I can parse what I get just fine, but I'm getting different data from two different servers which use the same data source.

Comment: So you have two database servers, correct? If you execute a simple `GETDATE()` on each server do you get the same result?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson no, both of these web servers are using the same database.  They both are retrieving the same exact timespan value and converting it the same exact way.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDateTime` will return a local time which is why you are getting different results for servers in different time zones.

Try:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(ts.ToString()).ToUniversalTime();
```

Which will return the UTC time.

Comment: I solved this by specifying the kind of datetime to UTC.
`var datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(ts.ToString());
var utcDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(datetime, DateTimeKind.Utc);`  Judging from the documentation on DateTime.ToUniversalTime() it sounds like that would still cause the time to be shifted inappropriately.